# Ember data store.find() creating empty items when called with an invalid id

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a list bound to model backed by a `DS.RecordArray`, as used the Ember data sample js fiddle. When I call `this.store.find({id}`) with a valid id, everything works as expected. However, when I call `this.store.find({id})` with either a non-existing id or an empty string, an empty model is added to the `DS.RecordArray`, which is reflected in my bound list.

I've created an example of this behavior in a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rafre75g/1/).  My example has two buttons to showcase two cases:

1. Calling `find('post', 14)` where 14 represents an id that does not exist. In this case, pressing this button once adds a blank element to the list and subsequent presses do nothing.
2. Calling `find('post', '')` where the empty string is passed instead of an id. In this case, every time this button is pressed, a blank element is added to the list.

Is this behavior expected? If so, what would be the best way to avoid these empty elements in my list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

store.find("type", id) will delegate to store.findById(type, id), which calls store.recordForId(type, id).  If you check out the function body of recordForId(), you'll see that it checks the typeMap for the id, and if it doesn't exist, calls buildRecord(type, id), which creates a record of that type and adds it to the typeMap.

It's expected behavior in that it's clearly intended to do so, but whether it's a good idea or not can be argued.

It's not a good idea, for my application, so I override the store.findById to Ember.assert() on the id being truthy, since I'm never trying to find a record with 0, null, or undefined id's.